# Adding item to listview through a dialog

Tags: android

I'm using a custom listview which I want to add an item to my listview.  But it seems to be skipping all the code to add the item. Can someone please tell me how I should adjust my code to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

This is my Main Activity in which I call a custom Dialog

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView threadId;
    ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button newMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_message_button);
        final Context context = this;

        final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.messagingListView);
        final ActivityAdapter itemAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.MessageFeedData());

        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                MessageItem itemAtPos = (MessageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConversationView.class);
                intent.putExtra("threadId", String.valueOf(itemAtPos.ThreadId));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        newMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.write_message_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                final Button post_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_post);
                final EditText new_write_message = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.messge_msg);
                final EditText to_message = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.to_newmsg);

                post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        items.add(new MessageItem(5458, to_message.getText().toString(), "imh", DateTime.now(), new_write_message.getText().toString()));

                        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        if (v.getId() == R.id.button_post);
                        to_message.setText("");
                        new_write_message.setText("");


                    }
                });

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }


    public ArrayList<MessageItem> MessageFeedData() {
        ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

        //recieved_item_click_actions fields
        items.add(new MessageItem(1, "Bob Doe", "image", DateTime.now(), "Hello how are you?"));
        items.add(new MessageItem(200, "Simon Pink", "image", DateTime.now(), "Hello what are you doing"));

        return items;
    }


    class ActivityFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTracks;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... page) {
            try {
                recentTracks = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

                Thread.sleep(3000);

                MessageItem data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    recentTracks.add(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageItem> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<MessageItem> items;
        //private int currentPage = 0;

        public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTrackArrayList) {
            super(context, 0, recentTrackArrayList);
            this.context = context;
            this.items = recentTrackArrayList;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;


            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate
                        (R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false);

                rowView = convertView;

                TextView comment2 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_username);
                comment2.setText(items.get(position).Username);

                ImageView comment3 = (ImageView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_photo);
                if (items.get(position).Image == null) {
                    comment3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }

                TextView comment4 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_date);
                comment4.setText(items.get(position).DateTimeStamp.toString());

                TextView comment5 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_string);
                comment5.setText(items.get(position).MessageString);

            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

This is my custom Dialog

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to_newmsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TO" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messge_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/to_newmsg"
        android:text="MESSAGE" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messge_msg"
        android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you want to create an Alert Dialog with the custom layout when the newMessage Button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
 ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();
```

before onCreate

while this

```
 ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();
```

in  MessageFeedData() is local.

Use a single list and add items to the same then call `notifyDateSetChanged()` to refresh listview.

As you can see you do not use `items` as an arg to constructor

```
 final ActivityAdapter itemAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.MessageFeedData());
```

Edit:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.messagingListView);
items = this.MessageFeedData());
final ActivityAdapter itemAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
```